Editing video - Navigation will not drag past 9h42min
Keyboard navigation works - Page up will navigate to the next video sequence
The moment I click on the timeline, the navigation jumps all the way back to 9hr42 min
I can drag the navigation anywhere BEFORE that time, but it will not drag anywhere beyond that time
I have spent 2 hours doing trouble shooting with chatgpt and forums, have not found help
Both the preview range and the regular range are set to all strips, end frame too. I have no keyframes. Increasing the memory cache did nothing.
This issue is big enough that it might force me to use an entirely different video editor if I can't do something as simple as navigate past 9hr42min


tbh i have no idea why it doesn't work (ok i might have one, but it wouldn't make you happy), but why do you wanna render a video over 9 hours in one file? Makes less sense to me. First it must take minutes to open that up (i assume). Second it must be incredible slow to work with. I would separate to different blend files that let's say max 30 mins per file and then render that and at the end combine them all via ffmpeg.

I agree with @Chris here... I do not know about your hardware, but my (not the current, but the previous) computer was a pain to work with on videos of about 10 minutes, I cannot imagine how almost 10 hours would have been. That's when I already switched to DaVinci Resolve which is much more performant then the VSE (sorry, Blender). Apart from that, even big motion pictures that are just a third or a quarter of yours in duration are edited in smaller chunks. Why does it have to be everything in a single file?

By the way, I just saw the frame number you're stuck at is 1048574. That is just slightly below 1048576, which is 2^20 or 1024 × 1024 frames. So I can only imagine this limit has something to do with memory or floating point limits etc. - don't ask me about specific technical reasons, this is just a guess because it is suspiciously close to a multiple of 2.

Thank you, it very well might be the frame limit on some variable
I switched to Kdriveline, and was able to edit the video onto a single timeline no problem, realtime is 24hrs
The intention is to create a timelapse, I was trying to do that by having all video clips present and then fitting them to a specific time or speed
From what I can tell the preview is limited but the capability is there
Fix in this case was to use an alternate program
Thanks!
